# Position:relative doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-position

I have table in div and in table is class .tabela which looks like this:

```
.tabela { position:relative; top:0px; margin-left:10px; background-color:black;}
.tabela td{ position:relative; top:0px;}
```

In Mozilla and Opera table is on top but in IE isn't, I have read that is bug in IE, but there is any solution to set table on top in IE ? Maybe with javascript when page has been loaded ?

```
<div class="top">
<table class="tabela">
<tr><td>
```

Thanks

Comment: The behaviour of `position: relative` on `td`s is undefined. What is this supposed to do in the first place?

Comment: I tried define position in td but without result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. This is untested and may not work, but worth a try.

```
.top{position:relative;}
.tabela{position:absolute;top:0px;margin-left:10px;background-color:black;}
```

I hope it helps you out.